# ICA: a question about the non-gaussian requirement

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, signal-processing, independent-component-analysis

I'm new in the ICA processing and I'm trying to understand the non-gaussian requirement. I read that the problem is that, if the composed data is $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{As}$ with $\mathbf{A}$ (unknown) mixing matrix and $\mathbf{s}$ (unknown) original signals, then in ICA framework the components of $\mathbf{s}$ can not be considered gaussian because no "pattern" can be found in  $\mathbf{x}$ to recover  a unique $\mathbf{A}$ (since any rotation is good). So my questions are:

1. (maybe a naive or stupid question, but I need to do to clarify my ideas): it seems that the problem is not that there is no solution, but that there are too many possible solutions. Why this should be a problem? If we see the problem as to estimate an $\mathbf{A}$ s.t. $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{As}$, we simply can tell that there are many solutions and return just one of them.. Where is my error?
2. The central Limit Theorem states that the sum of many independent signals goes toward the gaussian distribution, so ICA searches for the best non-gaussian $\mathbf{s}$. But, if the sum of many signals is gaussian, again we have that  no "pattern" can be found in $\mathbf{x}$ to recover  a unique $\mathbf{A}$ (again, any rotation is good), so we have the gaussian problem again. Where I wrong?

I apologize for the possibly stupid questions, but I think that there is something that is not clear to me.